# Strange error: cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`

Tags: rust

I have tried to reproduce the problem in a very tiny program (you can find it here [Rust REPL](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d0ee2e0f10ff6cd3023635ecf5f6f75d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Error {
        SomeError{
            description("SomeError")
        }
    }
}


pub struct Version {
    foo: u8,
}

pub struct Bar();

impl Bar {
    pub fn version() -> Result<Version, Error> {
        Ok(Version{foo: 1})
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tmp = Bar::version()?;
}
```

when trying to compile, I get the following:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
  --> src/main.rs:27:15
   |
27 |     let tmp = Bar::version()?;
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
```

HOWEVER, version is returning `Result<Version, Error>`. What is going on?

Comment: `version` isn't the function you're trying to use `?` in.

Comment: `main` returns `()` which is where the error is.

Comment: OMG!! :) silly me. Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You misunderstand the function that the operator is talking about:

> cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`

Is about *the function in which the expression appears* and not *the expression on which `?` is applied*:

- the function in which the expression appears is `main`.
- the expression to which `?` is applied is `Bar::version()?`.

Therefore, the compiler is complaining that you cannot use `?` in `main` because the return type of `main` is `()`.

---

You can use `-> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` as a return type for `main`:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let tmp = Bar::version()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, I have just realized I was misreading the error message :) haha!